# Register adapter without common interface and scanning assemblies

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. Scan a specific assembly (`RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)`).
2. Filter to a specific namespace (`.IsInNamespace("...")`) which will have stand-alone interfaces without a common base interface.
3. Register a generic adapter as a generic interface.(`.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Adapter<>)).As(typeof(IAdapter<>))`
4. I'll need several of these registrations and each set will use `IAdapter<>` with a different `Adapter<>` instance.

In other words, `IFoo` and `IBar` might be in namespace1 and `IAbc` in namespace2 and I want to register:

- `Adapter<IFoo>` as `IAdapter<IFoo>`
- `Adapter<IBar>` as `IAdapter<IBar>`
- `Adapter2<IAbc>` or `Adapter<IAbc>(customParams)` as `IAdapter<IAbc>`

To somewhat repeat myself, if I do my own scanning of assemblies to get the interfaces then I believe I can do something similar to this (untested):

```
Type interfaces[] = ...; // Scan assembly and filter to namespace1

foreach (Type interfaceType in interfaces)
{
    builder
        .Register(context => typeof(Adapter<>).MakeGenericType(interfaceType))
        .As(type => typeof(IAdapter<>).MakeGenericType(interfaceType));
}

interfaces = ...; // Interfaces in namespace2

foreach (Type interfaceType in interfaces)
{
    builder
        .Register(context => typeof(Adapter2<>).MakeGenericType(interfaceType))
        .As(type => typeof(IAdapter<>).MakeGenericType(interfaceType));
}
```

Is there any way do this out of the box using Autofac without doing my own scanning/looping?  I've looked at the Autofac [adapter support](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html#adapters), but that seems to only work with a common interface.  [RegisterGeneric](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html?highlight=registergeneric#open-generic-components) also helps, but only with one type of instance.

Answer (score 1):

*Autofac* has no built-in support to resolve a generic service based on the type of a generic parameter. By the way, you can use dynamic registration using a `IRegistrationSource` to do what you want.

Let's say you have these types :

```
namespace A
{
    interface IFoo { }
}
namespace B
{
    interface IBar { }
}

interface IAdapter<T> { }
class Adapter1<T> : IAdapter<T> { }
class Adapter2<T> : IAdapter<T> { }
class Foo : A.IFoo { }
class Bar : B.IBar { }
```

You want something like this :

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<A.IFoo>();
builder.RegisterType<Bar>().As<B.IBar>();

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Adapter1<>)).As(typeof(IAdapter<>));
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Adapter2<>)).As(typeof(IAdapter<>));

IContainer container = builder.Build();

var fooAdapter = container.Resolve<IAdapter<A.IFoo>>(); // should return Adapter1<Foo>()
var barAdapter = container.Resolve<IAdapter<B.IBar>>(); // should return Adapter2<Bar>()
```

When *Autofac* will resolve `IAdapter<T>` it has no way to find the concrete implementation based on the namespace of `T`.

A `IRegistrationSource` will allow you to dynamically register a type when *Autofac* needs it.

```
class TestRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    public Boolean IsAdapterForIndividualComponents
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(
        Service service, Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        IServiceWithType typedService = service as IServiceWithType;
        if (typedService == null)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        if (!(typedService.ServiceType.IsGenericType 
              && typedService.ServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IAdapter<>)))
        {
            yield break;
        }

        Type t = typedService.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        IComponentRegistration registration = 
            RegistrationBuilder.ForDelegate((c, p) => c.ResolveNamed(t.Namespace, typedService.ServiceType, p))
                               .As(service)
                               .CreateRegistration();

        yield return registration;
    }
}
```

This `IRegistrationSource` will register a new concrete implementation when *Autofac* need it. When *Autofac* needs a `IAdapter<A.Foo>` it will enter the `TestRegistrationSource` which will register a new `IAdapter<A.Foo>` as a delegate which will resolve a named generic registration of `IAdapter<T>`

In order to make the `TestRegistrationSource` works you have to change the registration of `Adapter1<T>` and `Adapter2<T>` to use generic named registration.

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Foo>().As<A.IFoo>();
builder.RegisterType<Bar>().As<B.IBar>();

builder.RegisterSource(new TestRegistrationSource());

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Adapter1<>)).Named("Namespace.A", typeof(IAdapter<>));
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Adapter2<>)).Named("Namespace.B", typeof(IAdapter<>));

IContainer container = builder.Build();

var fooAdapter = container.Resolve<IAdapter<A.IFoo>>(); // will return Adapter1<Foo>()
var barAdapter = container.Resolve<IAdapter<B.IBar>>(); // will return Adapter2<Bar>()
```